# Github actions does not see pm2 ecosystem.config.js

Tags: github-actions, devops, pm2, cicd, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

the root directory looks like this: actions-runner, ecosystem.config, server.

I have the config in the root directory, where I run the backend and the frontend. Github actions is used only for client and when actions starts, I get error "File ecosystem.config.js not found". I guess it can't find this file in the actions-runner folder, but I don't understand how I can access it from github actions

Error:

```
File ecosystem.config.js not found
```

Root directory:

```
actions_runner ecosystem.config.js  nodesource_setup.sh  server
```

Yml file:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
      

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --only client
```

Ecosystem.config.js

```
{
      name: 'strapi',
      cwd: 'myPath',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'client',
      cwd: '/myPath',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote "pm2 restart client" and no file is needed, now everything works